# C++: Undefined reference при линковке теста с либой

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компоновщик, clang

Вот исходник тесты

```
#include <common.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace RFw;

int main() {
    Array<int> _a_;

    _a_.resize(5);

    _a_[2] = 'b';
    _a_[3] = 'a';

    printf("%c%c\n", *(_a_.provideElement(2)), *(_a_.provideElement(3)));

    return 0;
}
```

Так компилю:

```
c++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -Isrc-core/ -Lbin/ -lcore
```

Вывод:

```
/tmp/test-k6aFM8.o: In function `main':                                                                                                                                                                              
test.cpp.text+0x27): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::Array(unsigned int, int*)'                                                                                                                           
test.cpp.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::resize(unsigned int)'                                                                                                                                
test.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::operator[](unsigned int)'                                                                                                                            
test.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::operator[](unsigned int)'                                                                                                                            
test.cpp:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::provideElement(unsigned int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::provideElement(unsigned int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::~Array()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `RFw::Array<int>::~Array()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

PS Array взят из Array.hpp который инклюдится в common.hpp

Array.hpp:

```
/**
 *      src-core/Array.hpp
 */
#ifndef _ARRAY_HPP_
#define _ARRAY_HPP_

#include "util.hpp"
#include "Object.hpp"
#include "arrayExceptions.hpp"

namespace RFw {
    template<typename TValue>
    class Array : public Object {
    public:
                                Array(intnum _length = 0, TValue* _array = nullptr);
        virtual                 ~Array();

        void                    addToTop(const TValue _element) throw(ArrayOverflowException);
        void                    addToEnd(const TValue _element) throw(ArrayOverflowException);
        void                    clone(const intnum _length, const TValue* _array);

        TValue*                 provideElement(const intnum _index) throw(IndexOutOfRangeException);
        const TValue*           provideElement(const intnum _index) const throw(IndexOutOfRangeException);

        TValue&                 operator[](const intnum _index) throw(IndexOutOfRangeException);
        const TValue&           operator[](const intnum _index) const throw(IndexOutOfRangeException);

        void                    resize(const intnum _newLentgh);

        const Array<TValue>     getClone() const;
        const intnum            getLength() const;
        const TValue*           getArray() const;
    private:
        intnum                  length__;
        TValue*                 array__;
    };
}

#endif //   _ARRAY_HPP_
```

Comment: @VladD, Значит что в исходниках либы всё ок, т.е. согласно статье. Тем более хедер используются прямо из исходников либы

Comment: @VladD, готово

Comment: @VladD, а где связь между "Я на своей стороне не могу создать нужные инстанциации" и "С шаблонами вы должны всегда помещать реализацию методов в header"?  
 --  
Я Вам показал, что с шаблонами совсем не обязательно помещать реализацию в header. Даже в случае разработки библиотеки. Sorry for this. ))

Comment: >я ж написал в первом же комменте, что реализация методов в хедере необязательна

Не было такого! И, кроме того, **должны всегда** Вы так и не удалили из ответа.

>Но ... она обязательна, если шаблон экспортируется библиотекой.

Шаблон невозможно экспортировать. Можно экспортировать только некоторые его реализации. Этим я Вас снова возвращаю к исходному вопросу: где же все таки озвученная связь?

Comment: @mega: Шаблон невозможно экспортировать? А что, по-вашему, делает весь stl? И почти весь boost? `std::vector` находится не в вашем проекте.

И я всё же считаю, что инстанциация конкретных реализаций шаблона — хак, правильное решение — реализация в хедере.

Comment: >Шаблон невозможно экспортировать? А что, по-вашему, делает весь stl?

@VladD, не позорьтесь!

>>@VladD, это был не аргумент. Это был вопрос. Давайте я Вам его повторю: где связь между "Я на своей стороне не могу создать нужные инстанциации" и "С шаблонами вы должны всегда помещать реализацию методов в header"? Вы же не будете утверждать, что не поняли вопрос ))

Comment: @VladD Extremist-programming? ( http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/11/extremist-programming/ )

Comment: @mega: А по-вашему стандартная библиотека — не библиотека? Или boost? `std::vector< my_cool_struct >` работает лишь потому, что весь `std::vector` определён в header'е.

@alexlz: ещё какой экстремист! Мысль о том, что код надо писать по-разному в зависимости от того, он в библиотеке или нет, кажется мне глубоко неправильной. PS: хорошая ссылка, спасибо, прочитал с удовольствием.

Comment: >А по-вашему стандартная библиотека —не библиотека?

@VladD, Вы сейчас пытаетесь уйти от неправильной формулировки, которую защищаете. Я Вам даже пример показал с реализацией библиотеки. Фокус не засчитан )) Вы нам на вопрос-то ответите или нет?  
 --
>Вы ведь понимаете, что ваш пример с реализацией библиотеки не катит (и почему)?

Ох, Вы там даже ошибку нашли?! Т.е., ответа не будет? Очень печально ( Разочарован  
 --  
p.s.: пришлось удалить коммент:

>а откуда 3.lib возьмётся? Авторы библиотеки ведь не сидят в соседней комнате

---

>Вы меня не поняли или не захотели понять - это печально 

Comment: @mega: Вы ведь понимаете, что ваш пример с реализацией библиотеки не катит (и почему)?

По модулю этого ответ на вопрос: Связь простая. Код должен быть написан правильно. Если реализацию положить в .cpp, тот, кто _пользуется_ шаблоном, должен будет заботиться об его инстанциациях. А это неправильно, так как код при этом потеряет модульность и приобретёт сильную связность (шаблон должен будет знать обо всех своих «клиентах»).

Comment: @mega: то есть вы всё ещё уверены в своём примере? Сможете сделать его в виде проекта, чтобы компилировался, и выложить, чтобы я смог откомпилировать у себя? (Visual Studio или gcc подойдёт.)

Напомню setup: (1) в библиотеке определён шаблон `template <typename T> class Array`, (2) имплементация находится в .cpp, (3) пользователь библиотеки может без ошибок компоновки использовать `Array<my_cool_struct>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С шаблонами вы **должны** помещать реализацию методов в header.

В вашем случае пишите так:

```
template<typename TValue>
class Array : public Object {
public:
    Array(intnum _length = 0, TValue* _array = nullptr) :
        length__(_length),
        array__(new TValue[_length]) {
        // остаток имплементации
    }
    virtual  ~Array() {
        delete[] array__;
    }
    // и так далее
};
```

Если вы вынесете реализацию методов в .cpp-файл, компилятор не будет знать, какие инстанциации шаблона ему нужно компилировать. Это [ограничение модели компиляции языка C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl). Sorry for this.

---

Небольшое объяснение. В C++ шаблон не есть класс, это лишь «описание», по которому при подстановке шаблонных аргументов генерируется реальный класс. Никакого объектного кода шаблон сам по себе не производит.

Когда компилятор компилирует C++-файл с кодом, использующим шаблон, он видит, с каким шаблонным аргументом используется этот шаблон. Но когда он компилирует C++-файл с реализацией шаблонных методов, он не знает, с какими аргументами инстанциировался шаблон в других файлах, ведь каждый C++-файл компилируется по отдельности!

Поэтому решением является положить реализацию *внутрь шаблонного класса*. При этом компилятор в той точке, где он видит инстанциацию шаблона, видит *весь* его код, и может скомпилировать все методы класса.

(Существует ещё уродливый костыль с указанием в C++-файле точного списка инстанциаций шаблона, который настолько ужасен, что я не хочу о нём и говорить. Аналогом этому было бы около каждой функции указывать заранее список всех аргументов, с которым функция будет вызвана в программе.)

Comment: >Если вы вынесете реализацию методов в .cpp-файл, компилятор не будет знать, какие инстанциации шаблона ему нужно компилировать. 

Это если только не скомпилировать в `cpp` конкретные специализации шаблона, которые только и используются в проекте. В таком случае реализации шаблонов можно спокойно выносить из заголовочных файлов. "Всегда" здесь лишнее!

Comment: Большое спасибо, я с этим недели полторы не мог разобраться

Comment: @mega: Согласен, был слишком категоричен. Тем не менее, для библиотеки такой подход всё равно неприемлем: откуда библиотечному `.cpp` знать, с какими типами клиент будет инстанциировать шаблон?

Для небиблиотечного кода подход, о котором вы говорите, может быть хорошей альтернативой.

Comment: >откуда библиотечному .cpp знать, с какими типами клиент будет инстанциировать шаблон?

Фишка статической библиотеки, которая мне тут оч. нравится, в том, что **ей и не нужно покрывать все объявленные `externals`**. Они вполне могут быть реализованы в другой библиотеке, или вообще `user`-кодом. Даже просто из соображений модульной разработки ПО и оптимизации процедуры сборки больших проектов этот вариант более чем приемлем.

Comment: @mega: Ничего не понял — мой C++ возможно немного заржавел от нечастого использования. Можете показать пример с кодом?

Comment: a.h:

 template< int a>
 struct A{
   A( void );
 };

1.lib.cpp:

 #include "a.h"
 ...
 template<>
 A<1>::A( void ){ printf( "1" ); }

2.lib.cpp:

 #include "a.h"
 ...
 template<>
 A<2>::A( void ){ printf( "2" ); }

exec.cpp:

 #include "a.h"
 #pragma comment( lib, "1" )
 #pragma comment( lib, "2" )
 ...
 A<1>a1;
 A<2>a2;

Comment: @mega: Хм, я ожидал большего. Смотрите, библиотека должна _заранее_ знать, с какими типами её клиенту вздумается её инстанциировать. А если я в `exec.cpp` захочу использовать `A<3>`, я получу принципиально неустраняемую ошибку линковки.

Comment: >я получу принципиально неустраняемую ошибку линковки
Ой, какая же страшная это ошибка! Если вам вздумается использовать `A<3>`, Вы подключите `3.lib`.  
 --  
А вот, если все реализации запихать инлайном в один шаблон, и если, к примеру размер той же реализации `A<3>` многократно превышает остальные, то каждая сборка `exec` будет большую часть времени компилировать этот самый `A<3>`, даже если Вы на данный момент работаете с `A<1>` или `A<2>` и делали изменения только в них.  
 --  
Вот Вам и оптимизация!

Comment: @mega: Ну это да, а откуда 3.lib возьмётся? Авторы библиотеки ведь не сидят в соседней комнате, они расположены в другой части земного шара и говорят только на гуджарати (к примеру).

Comment: Ссылку поправили, а вот замечание про "всегда" не учли :(

Comment: @alexolut: Я до сих пор категорически не согласен с этим замечанием. Если хотите, дайте альтернативный ответ.

Comment: Ну, дело не только в явном инстанцировании шаблонов. Если шаблон фактически используется только в одном модуле, нет смысла держать его в заголовочном файле, можно разместить и в .cpp.

Comment: @alexolut: Это да, локальный класс тоже решение. В любом случае: _раздельная компиляция не работает с шаблонами_, поскольку шаблоны не производят объектный код.

Comment: @VladD могут быть и более частные ситуации, например, приватная шаблонная функция-член, тип из которой не пролезает наружу. В этом случае реализацию этой функции также можно поместить в .cpp, а в определении класса оставить только объявление.

Comment: @alexolut: Бывают и случаи, когда вы точно знаете список всех аргументов, с которыми вы вызовете данную функцию `f(int x)`. Мой аргумент состоит в том, что инлайн-реализация работает _всегда_, а попытка реализовать раздельную компиляцию работает только в нескольких частных случаях, и легко ломается.

Comment: *Всегда работает* это ещё ведь не значит, что это всегда правильно. Можно вообще всю программу в одном файле написать, это тоже *всегда работает*.

Comment: @alexolut: Я даже и не знаю, что ответить. Раздельная компиляция нешаблонов работает **всегда**, и поэтому и записать всё в одном файле, и применить раздельную компиляцию правильно. Раздельная компиляция шаблонов работает только в редких, исключительных случаях, и поэтому она неверна. Я это повторил несколько раз, но для вас почему-то это не является аргументом.

Comment: @alexolut: Если ваша позиция состоит в том, что «в том редком случае, когда работает, можно применять», я позволю себе напомнить про нарушение strict aliasing или любом другом UB, которое тоже _иногда работает_. Если вы отстаиваете озвученную мной позицию, вы должны тогда одобрять и опору на UB в коде?

Comment: Нет смысла размещать реализацию шаблона в хедере, если она там не нужна. Вот и всё что я хочу сказать. Ровно так же как мы не делаем все поля открытыми для пользователя, нет смысла открывать лишний код для компилятора.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну давайте разовьём этот метод рассуждения. «Не стоит делать поля закрытыми, если это не нужно вот в данном месте.» «Не стоит использовать синхронизацию, если приложение не валится.» «Не стоит фиксить баги, если можно и так продать продукт.» Мне такой метод рассуждения не нравится, он совершенно точно не всегда подходит. И мне непонятно, почему он подходит в нашем случае.

Comment: Если такой метод рассуждения Вам не нравится, зачем Вы пишите, что `С шаблонами вы должны **всегда помещать** реализацию методов в header.`? **Не** должен и **не** всегда, но в текущей задаче их следует разместить именно там.

Comment: @alexolut: Мы ходим кругами. Потому что это нехрупкое решение, которое работает всегда.

Comment: @alexolut: «Должны» не в смысле «иначе никогда не будет работать», а в смысле «это единственное хорошее решение».

Comment: @VladD ну, это уже многое меняет. Но я вот воспринимаю "должны" исключительно как первый вариант :)

Comment: @alexolut: Тогда, думаю, мы в первом приближении мы достигли консенсуса.