# Ошибка undefined reference

Tags: c++

Добрый "вечер". Прошу помощи с ошибкой линковщика. Имеется два взаимосвязанных класса (Enemy & Container).

### Enemy.h

```
#pragma once
...
#include "Container.h"
class Enemy{
public:
    ...
    void effect(std::shared_ptr<Effect>);
    ...
private:
    ...
    Container<std::shared_ptr<Effect>> effects;
    ...
};
```

### Container.h

```
#pragma once
...
class Enemy;

template <class T>
class Container{
public:
    void add_with_action(T, Enemy&);
};
```

### Enemy.cpp

```
...
void Enemy::effect(std::shared_ptr<Effect> effect){
    effects.add_with_action(effect, *this);
}
...
```

### Container.cpp

```
#include "Container.h"
template<class T>
void Container<T>::add_with_action(T effect, Enemy& en){
    ...
}
template<class T>
void Container<T>::expired(T effect){
    ...
}
```

Во время make появляется ошибка:

> Game/Enemy.o: In function
> `Enemy::effect(std::shared_ptr<Effect>)':
> Enemy.cpp:(.text+0x952): undefined reference to
> Container<std::shared_ptr<Effect>::expired(std::shared_ptr<Effect>)'
> Enemy.cpp:(.text+0x98f): undefined reference to`Container<std::shared_ptr<Effect>::add_with_action(std::shared_ptr<Effect>,
> Enemy&)' collect2: error: ld returned
> 1 exit status

Если я правильно понимаю, то проблема в том, что классы зависят друг от друга.

Comment: Проблема не в том, что классы зависят друг от друга, а в том, что линковщик не может найти код, который нужно вставить в исполняемый файл. Очень интересно было б поискать в заголовочных файлах и файлах с  исходными кодами `Container::add_with_action()` и `Container::expired`. Возможно чего-то в исходниках не хватает - не по злому умыслу, а просто оно есть в другом месте. Соб-сно, и где же `Container.cpp`?

Comment: Container.cpp я не выкладывал, ибо там совсем ничего особенного нет. Сейчас прикреплю его к посту.

Comment: @VladD, так в CPP перенести или в заголовочный файл?

Comment: @gecube: в заголовочный файл, конечно, очепятка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, неплохо бы реализацию методов template-класса `Container` перенести в header. Смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/270465#270534

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо! Перенес в header и теперь собирается без ошибок.

Comment: @sazor: перенёс в ответ.