# Прототипы функций в заголовочном файле

Tags: c++, header

Допустим есть .cpp файл в котором мной написано некоторое количество функций стоит ли для него делать заголовочный файл с прототипами функций или можно переименовать его в .h файл и просто его подключать как обычный заголовок? что лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, правильный путь — это конечно вынести прототипы отдельно, а имплементацию отдельно. Таким путём вы получаете преимущества *раздельной компиляции*: ваши функции компилируются отдельно, лишь один раз.

В случае, когда функции находятся в header'е, они будут компилироваться *каждый* раз при включении этого самого header'а. Кроме того, вам придётся каждую функцию обозначить как `inline`, чтобы компоновщик не ругался на множественные определения.

(Немного офтопика: `inline` в C++ *не означает* «встрой эту функцию в место вызова вместо реального вызова». Такими оптимизациями заведует компилятор и только он. Смысл `inline` именно такой: сообщить компоновщику, что функции с одним именем, которые он видит в разных модулях — это одна и та же функция, и не нужно выдавать ошибку.)

Ещё одна проблема, которую позволяют изящно решать `header`'ы — зависимости. Например, рассмотрим взаимно-рекурсивные функции. Когда вы пользуетесь функцией `f`, вы можете вызвать в ней другую функцию `g`. Допустим, вы пишете ваши функции в header'е. Если функция `g` определена *ниже* функции `f`, вам придётся ещё и добавлять декларацию функции `g`. В случае, если имплементация находится вне header'а, проблема не возникает (но зато, конечно, вам приходится делать декларации *всех* функций).

(Особенно остро проблема зависимостей стоит в случае *классов*, содержащих ссылки друг на друга, т. к. в header всё равно обычно выносят определение данных класса, включая приватные поля!)

Существуют, однако, случаи, когда код *приходится* держать в header'е. Например, шаблонные функции (да и классы) должны быть в нём, иначе у вас могут быть проблемы с инстанциацией.

Comment: спасибо все понятно. только вот что обозначает термин в вашем ответе - инстанциация? так для полноты понимания спрашиваю

Comment: @perfect: Сейчас поищу, у нас был тут вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: @perfect: [Вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/270534/10105).

Comment: спасибо за помощь  @VlaD

Comment: @perfect: Смотрите: template не компилируется, компилируется только конкретный «экземпляр» с конкретными типами аргументов (то есть например не `vector<T>` вообще, а конкретный `vector<int>` и `vector<string>`). При этом компилятор не знает заранее, какие именно типы ему понадобятся — откуда ему знать? Поэтому происходит следующее:

Comment: @perfect: ... как только компилятор видит, например, `vector<int>`, он производит _инстанциацию_ шаблона: тихонько незаметно компилирует для себя `vector<int>` как нормальный класс. И это он делает во время компиляции **вашего** кода! А значит, он **должен** в этот момент видеть полный текст шаблона `vector`. Поэтому этот весь текст вынужден быть в header'е.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта хороши.

С точки зрения времени компиляции, чем больше .cpp файлов, тем больше время полной перекомпиляции, и тем меньше время частичной (когда перекомпилируются только измененные файлы). И наоборот - при малом количестве .cpp файлов, время полной перекомпиляции приближается к времени частичной перекомпиляции.

Если размещать код только в .hpp файлах - не надо писать прототипы функций. Получается меньше кода, а значит код проще рефакторить. (При этом не надо забывать помечать функции как `inline`)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы собираетесь использовать эти функции в других файлах тебе лучше вынести прототипы в заголовочный файл, не забудь о Include guard в заголочном файле.

```
    **header.h** 
    #ifndef H_HEADER
    #define H_HEADER
     
    void foo();
    #endif

    ****
    **functions.cpp**
    #include "header.h"
    void foo()
    {
         ****
    };
```

Но это рекомендации для лучшей читаемости, чтобы прототипы выводились в заголовочный файл. Вы можете переименовать свой cpp файл и включать его другие файлы, но лучше так не делать.

Comment: @Abyx: Но это всё же нестандартное расширение, ЕМНИП. Хотя основные компиляторы его таки поддерживают.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще добавить, что часто есть соблазн оставить в хедере тривиальные гетеры/сетеры классов. Такой вариант имеет право на жизнь, если есть уверенность, что так оно в дальнейшем все и останется. Но в целом такое могут посчитать дурным тоном из-за понятных переделок/перекомпиляций в случае, когда любой из таких методов перестанет быть тривиальным.