# Не могу скомпилить демки AGG (Anti-Grain Geometry) на Билдере/MinGW, не понимаю на что оно ругается

Tags: c++, c++builder, mingw

Здравствуйте!

Я ещё только учусь, и столкнулся вот с такой проблемой...
Почитал об AGG, заинтересовался, скачал. Попытался скомпилить идущие в комплекте демки через "Билдер 6". Не вышло, подумал ну мож очередной баг Билдера - скачал и поставил MinGW.
Пока повозился с ним, понатыкался на непонятные проблемы, вроде основы разобрал - а всё равно не компилит, гадина...
Ошибки странные, не понимаю их, вернее с какого чёрта они вылезли, нагуглить не удалось похожего.

Итак, у меня WinXP (лицензия), GCC 5.3.0, AGG-117. Пытаюсь компилить так:

```
> C:\Dev\AGG\examples>g++ gradients.cpp -o gradients.exe -I"C:\Dev\AGG\Include"

Получаю какую-то чертовщину:

> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::caption(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::init(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::run()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj[__ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj]+0x2d): undefined reference to `agg::g_elder_bit_table'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj[__ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj]+0x57): undefined reference to `agg::g_elder_bit_table'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj[__ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj]+0x81): undefined reference to `agg::g_elder_bit_table'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj[__ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj]+0x97): undefined reference to `agg::g_elder_bit_table'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj[__ZN3agg9fast_sqrtEj]+0xd7): undefined reference to `agg::g_sqrt_table'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg12trans_affinemLERKS0_[__ZN3agg12trans_affinemLERKS0_]+0x15): undefined reference to `agg::trans_affine::multiply(agg::trans_affine const&)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationD1Ev[__ZN15the_applicationD1Ev]+0x21): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::full_file_name(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationD1Ev[__ZN15the_applicationD1Ev]+0x9e2): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::values(double*, double*, double*, double*) const'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationD1Ev[__ZN15the_applicationD1Ev]+0xabc): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::~platform_support()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationD1Ev[__ZN15the_applicationD1Ev]+0xb57): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::~platform_support()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x33): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::platform_support(agg::pix_format_e, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x3d3): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::border_width(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x56d): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::border_width(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x591): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::border_width(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x5b5): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::border_width(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x5d9): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::border_width(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x601): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::border_width(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x629): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x659): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x689): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x6b9): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x6e9): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x711): more undefined references to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)' follow
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x726): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x74b): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x77b): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x7ab): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x7db): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x80b): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x833): more undefined references to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)' follow
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x848): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x86d): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x89d): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x8cd): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x8fd): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x92d): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x955): more undefined references to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)' follow
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x96a): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x98f): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x9bb): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x9e7): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xa13): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xa3f): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xa67): more undefined references to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)' follow
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xa7c): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xa95): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::add_item(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xab1): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::add_item(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xacd): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::add_item(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xae9): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::add_item(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xb05): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::add_item(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xb21): more undefined references to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::add_item(char const*)' follow
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xb54): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::full_file_name(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xc99): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xd05): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xd71): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xddd): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xe49): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0xeb5): more undefined references to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::point(unsigned int, double, double)' follow
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x1662): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x1674): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x1686): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x1698): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::update_spline()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x1749): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::values(double, double, double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb[__ZN15the_applicationC1EN3agg12pix_format_eEb]+0x17ef): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::~platform_support()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application7on_drawEv[__ZN15the_application7on_drawEv]+0xdc): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::text_size(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application7on_drawEv[__ZN15the_application7on_drawEv]+0x4b1): undefined reference to `agg::trans_affine::invert()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application13on_mouse_moveEiij[__ZN15the_application13on_mouse_moveEiij]+0xbc): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::force_redraw()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application13on_mouse_moveEiij[__ZN15the_application13on_mouse_moveEiij]+0x103): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::force_redraw()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application13on_mouse_moveEiij[__ZN15the_application13on_mouse_moveEiij]+0x1f3): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::force_redraw()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application20on_mouse_button_downEiij[__ZN15the_application20on_mouse_button_downEiij]+0xc6): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::force_redraw()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application6on_keyEiijj[__ZN15the_application6on_keyEiijj]+0x24): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::full_file_name(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN15the_application6on_keyEiijj[__ZN15the_application6on_keyEiijj]+0x15f): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::full_file_name(char const*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg15gamma_ctrl_implD2Ev[__ZN3agg15gamma_ctrl_implD2Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for agg::gamma_ctrl_impl'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEC1Eddddb[__ZN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEC1Eddddb]+0x9c): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::gamma_ctrl_impl(double, double, double, double, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg16spline_ctrl_implD2Ev[__ZN3agg16spline_ctrl_implD2Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for agg::spline_ctrl_impl'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEC1Eddddjb[__ZN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEC1Eddddjb]+0xa3): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::spline_ctrl_impl(double, double, double, double, unsigned int, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg14rbox_ctrl_implD2Ev[__ZN3agg14rbox_ctrl_implD2Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for agg::rbox_ctrl_impl'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEC1Eddddb[__ZN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEC1Eddddb]+0x9c): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::rbox_ctrl_impl(double, double, double, double, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j[__ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j]+0x15): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::rewind(unsigned int)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j[__ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j]+0x47): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::vertex(double*, double*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j[__ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j]+0x15): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::rewind(unsigned int)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j[__ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j]+0x47): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::vertex(double*, double*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j[__ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j]+0x15): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::rewind(unsigned int)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.text$_ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j[__ZN3agg22rasterizer_scanline_aaINS_18rasterizer_sl_clipINS_12ras_conv_intEEEE8add_pathINS_9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEEEEvRT_j]+0x47): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::vertex(double*, double*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV15the_application[__ZTV15the_application]+0x10): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::on_init()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV15the_application[__ZTV15the_application]+0x14): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::on_resize(int, int)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV15the_application[__ZTV15the_application]+0x18): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::on_idle()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV15the_application[__ZTV15the_application]+0x2c): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::on_ctrl_change()'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV15the_application[__ZTV15the_application]+0x34): undefined reference to `agg::platform_support::on_post_draw(void*)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::in_rect(double, double) const'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x14): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_button_down(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_button_up(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x1c): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_move(double, double, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg9rbox_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `agg::rbox_ctrl_impl::on_arrow_keys(bool, bool, bool, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::in_rect(double, double) const'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x14): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_button_down(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_button_up(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x1c): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_move(double, double, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg11spline_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `agg::spline_ctrl_impl::on_arrow_keys(bool, bool, bool, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::in_rect(double, double) const'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x14): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_button_down(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_button_up(double, double)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x1c): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::on_mouse_move(double, double, bool)'
> C:\DOCUME~1\Samsung\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccrIUawl.o:gradients.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE[__ZTVN3agg10gamma_ctrlINS_6rgba8TINS_6linearEEEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `agg::gamma_ctrl_impl::on_arrow_keys(bool, bool, bool, bool)'
> c:/dev/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

В библиотеке AGG нету ни *.lib ни *.cpp, только *.h файлы.

В файле install написано примерно такое:

> Anti-Grain Geometry is a C++ library distributed in sources
>   and does not require any installation procedure. The source code 
>   is platform independent and does not have any dependencies on 
>   system APIs (except for very standard C runtime library).
>   You just take source files and include them into 
>   your project.

и такое:

> On Windows there's no library or a DLL created at all. You just
>   add source files into your project or create a preoject to build 
>   a LIB/DLL if you wish.

Установка не требуется, просто укажите где лежат *.h файлы. Что-то не так перевёл?

Я не понимаю как это "добавить в проект" или "собрать". Там только *.cpp с кодом демки в котором инклудятся *.h фалы.

Подумал может нельзя компилить с ключём -I"", скопировал содержимое "C:\Dev\AGG\include" в "C:\Dev\MinGW\include" - теперь находит без этого ключа, но ошибка та же.

Говорите "скопировать в проект"? Ну ок, скопировал содержимое папки "C:\Dev\AGG\include" в папку с исходниками демки "C:\Dev\AGG\examples" - ничего не изменилось.

Я не понимаю что мне нужно сделать.

Comment: Похоже, что помимо заголовочных файлов, вам надо указать, оде находятся объектные файлы пакета или соответствующая библиотека.

Comment: уже [подобных вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/270465/c-undefined-reference-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9) много. Это ошибки при линковке. Вас не смутило что в include только h файлы ? Вообще там есть док по использованию (файл install), где сказано что нужно либо сначала собрать AGG, либо скопировать все исходники себе в проект.

Comment: Отдельное и огромное спасибо тому кто "починил" мой вопрос!

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin , вопрос мой починили и обновили.
Вообще в папке AGG был html файл где пишут про некий "CMake", я его скачал и установил, сделал как было написано - какие-то незнакомые ошибки вылезли и всё.
Я просто не понимаю чего ему не хватает. "_Вас не смутило что в include только h файлы?_" - нет, а должно было? Вся реализация же в них. Что ему ещё надо-то?
Надо вручную создать к каждому h соответствующий cpp что ли? Подскажите...

Comment: Помогите же кто-то...
http://www.antigrain.com/doc/introduction/introduction.agdoc.html#toc0010

Comment: @An a Student, Вам бы попроще сначала пособирать проекты, там есть папка src и есть include. Реализация как раз в src, и поэтому нужно сначала собрать библиотеку, что бы использовать ёё и только h файлы, или скопировать к себе и include и src

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin , ну вообще я планировал просто написать одним файлом cpp минимальное приложение WinAPI (для учебных целей) и дополнительно использовать в нём AGG. Как "собирать" я вовсе не знаю. Погуглил вот, то есть я верно понимаю что у меня в -I"" должно указываться путь до папки с h файлами, а в -L"" путь до папки с файлами "lib" если для MS VS или файлами "a" для MinGW? И файлы "lib" или "a" надо делать самому? А как? В архиве AGG до чёртиков разных "makefile*" всяких. Но этот CMake никак не работает. Создаёт папку, но какие-то ошибки и нету файлов собранных.

Comment: А если просто копированием файлов - как и куда копировать? Все в "C:\Dev\MinGW\include"? Чтот не заработало. Может не всё или не туда сделал...

Comment: И так и сяк крутил копирование тех файлов из двух папок - не работает. :(

Comment: А вы-то не пробовали, получилось?