# Перегрузка оператора присваивания в шаблоне класса C++

Tags: c++-cli

Добрый день.
Пишу программу которая имеет следующую структуру:

**class baseSC** - содержит переменную ***token*** признака системы координат;

```
#pragma once

ref class baseSC
{
protected:
    int token; //признак системы координат
public:
    baseSC(void);
    virtual ~baseSC(void);
};
```

**class PZ90 : public baseSC** - содержит 2 переменные (***a*** - большая полуось, ***alfa*** - сжатие) и методы доступа к указанным переменным и переменной ***token***;

```
#pragma once
#include "baseSC.h"

ref class PZ90 : public baseSC
{
    int a; //большая полуось
    double alfa; //сжатие

public:
    PZ90(void);
    int getToken(void);
    int getA(void);
    int getAlfa(void);
};
```

**template `<`class T`>` ref class point** - Содержит ***ID_SC*** -идентификатор системы координат и ***elepType*** - экземпляр класса системы координат которая передается в виде параметра шаблона.

```
#pragma once
#include "baseSC.h"

template <class T> 
ref class point
{
    T elepType;
    int ID_SC;

public:
    point(void) {};
    int getTypeOfElemp () {return elepType.getToken();}
    int getID_SC () {return ID_SC;}
    void setID_SC(int input) {ID_SC = input;}
};
```

И наконец:
**template `<`class T`>` ref class pointGeodez: public point`<`T`>`**
и
**template "class T" ref class pointGeocent : public point`<`T`>`**
2 класса собственно точек где хранятся сами координаты и методы преобразования из одного класса в другой.

```
#pragma once
#include "PZ90.h"
#include "point.h"

template <class T>
ref class pointGeocent : public point<T>
{
    double geocentX, geocentY, geocentZ;
public:
    pointGeocent(void) {setID_SC(2);} // 2 - геоцентрчиеская СК

    void setX(double input) {geocentX = input;}
    void setY(double input) {geocentY = input;}
    void setZ(double input) {geocentZ = input;}

    double getX() {return geocentX;}
    double getY() {return geocentX;}
    double getZ() {return geocentX;}

    void convertToGeodez();
    void convertToGeocent();

    point<T> operator= (point<T>);
};
```

и

```
#pragma once
#include "PZ90.h"
#include "point.h"

template <class T>
ref class pointGeodez : public point<T>
{
    double geodezB, geodezL, geodezH;       
public:
    pointGeodez(void) {setID_SC(1);} // 1 - геодезическая СК

    void setB(double input) {geodezB = input;}
    void setL(double input) {geodezL = input;}
    void setH(double input) {geodezH = input;}

    double getB() {return geodezB;}
    double getL() {return geodezL;}
    double getH() {return geodezH;}

    void convertToGeocent();
    void convertToGeodez();

    void operator= (point<T>);
};
```

Все это сделано для того, что бы в случае необходимости можно было легко добавить дополнительные системы координат. Например вместо системы координат `ПЗ-90` использовать `WGS-84`, или вместо геоцентрической использовать систему координат с точкой начала отсчета в любом другом месте.

В файле **Form1.h** создаю 4 точки:

```
pointGeodez<PZ90> myPointObjGeodez;
pointGeocent<PZ90> myPointObjGeocent;
pointGeodez<PZ90> myPointTIGeodez;
pointGeocent<PZ90> myPointTIGeocent;
```

А вопрос следующий: почему не получается перегрузить оператор присваивания?

```
myPointObjGeocent = myPointObjGeodez;
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> error C2679: бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "pointGeodez" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

И если убрать строчку с присваиванием, и попытаться применить метод

```
myPointObjGeocent.convertToGeodez();
```

получаем ошибку:

> error LNK2020: неразрешенная лексема (0600001C) pointGeocent::convertToGeodez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы программируете на C++/CLI как будто на C++. Для управляемых объектов действуют другие правила, не такие как для нативных объектов.

Давайте посмотрим, что означает `myPointObjGeocent = myPointObjGeodez;`. Исходя из типов ваших объектов, вы вызываете функцию `pointGeocent<PZ90>::оператор = (point<PZ90>)`, берущую параметр *по значению*, и передаёте на вход параметр типа `pointGeodez<PZ90>`.

Для того, чтобы это скомпилировалось, вам нужно «превратить» `pointGeodez<PZ90>` в `point<PZ90>`. Но в C++/CLI для управляемых объектов нету «конвертации» из производного класса в базовый с потерей данных. Вот более простой пример:

```
ref class base {};
ref class derived : public base {};

void f(base) {}
```

```
derived d;
f(d); // не компилируется
```

---

Почему здесь будет потеря данных (slicing), и чем это опасно? Тем, что внутри оператора = аргумент имеет жёстко обозначенный тип `point<T>`, для него отводится ровно столько места, сколько нужно объекту `point<T>`. Полям производного объекта просто негде разместиться. Поэтому вы незаметно для пользователя создаёте объект не того типа, который создавал пользователь. Поскольку это может приводить к неприятным ошибкам (например: двойная деинициализация объектов-полей), в .NET это запрещено.

---

В C++, особенно в начале его существования, довольно часто объекты содержали лишь POD-данные, и особенных проблем не было. Но при наличии среди полей указателя [приходилось писать](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) обязательно виртуальный деструктор и перегружать оператор присваивания. В .NET обычно работа с объектами ведётся по ссылке, и случай необходимости дополнительных методов является не редким, а типичным. Поэтому slicing в .NET запрещён.

---

Вам стоит использовать типичные для .NET подходы, и отказаться от размещения объектов ссылочных типов на стеке. В этом случае ваш условный код будет таким:

```
ref class base {};
ref class derived : public base {};

void f(base^) {}

derived^ d = gcnew derived();
f(d); // компилируется
```

---

А вторая ошибка вызвана тем, что в C++/CLI, как и в C++, вы не должны размещать реализацию шаблонного класса вне header'а, т. к. шаблоны C++ (в отличие от генериков .NET) — не классы, а лишь описания классов, и не компилируются в объектный код. Посмотрите, например, [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/270534/10105).